# Adding Webpack to existing React app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server

So I have built the first piece of an app using `create-react-app`. It by default is using `npm` for building, running locally, etc...

What I want to do is to move to using Webpack, but not breaking the existing setup and have done some googling, but nothing starts and goes step by step so I can get a better feel for what it is doing and where it is going. Would like to also incorporate using `webpack-dev-server` with this as well.

That said, I was hoping you guys had some recommendations and maybe also point out some good tutorials for this moving forward?

Thanks much.

Comment: create-react-app actually uses webpack, but hides the configuration from the user. You can run `npm eject`, this will allow you to change webpack config and it won't break your existing setup.

Comment: As @dostu said, customizing configuration goes against the [Philosophy](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app#philosophy) of create-react-app. Custom configuration requires an eject. This excerpt from the [readme](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app#why-use-this) explains the reasoning "The feature set is intentionally limited. It doesn’t support advanced features such as server rendering or CSS modules. The tool is also non-configurable because it is hard to provide a cohesive experience and easy updates across a set of tools when the user can tweak anything"

Answer (score 4):

Create react app uses Webpack.
If you want to modify Webpack.config for this project you can run yarn eject/npm eject from here on you are responsible for the Webpack.config so it will be harder to update react scripts.

If you don't want to be responsible for the Webpack.config you could try to use react-app-rewired.